# Replacement for ArcScripts

Tags: arcpy

Does an equivalent of ArcScripts exist?

I know of the the ArcGIS resource center and "Code Galleries" but does something that equates to ArcScripts where users share useful ArcGIS code exist? The new ArcGIS forums are not great for searching for code either.

It seems to me as through the ESRI replacement for ArcScripts are a poor replacement and I am wondering if something 3rd party exists.  I know we can still search ArcScripts but it does not appear to still be an active repository.